# Rails errors.full_messages rendering square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looping through errors in a `user#update` using the following HAML:

```
- if @user.errors.any?
  .alert.alert-error
    %ul
      = @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

However, instead of just displaying the message, I also get square brackets:

`First name can't be blank ["First name can't be blank"]`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I do `p msg` then the console tail shows *only* the message, but within the `<li>` the brackets still render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The line:

`= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|`

should have read:

`- @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|`

Haml was printing out the array on top of doing the loop.